# How to access "index" propery in Flutter Widget: minhhung2556 / romantic_project_flutter_horizontal_featured_list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter / Dart so sorry if this is a dumb question.
I'm trying the "flutter_horizontal_featured_list" widget but don't know how to access item index inside onPressedItem? As this method is outside itemBuilder I can't seem to access the index property...

Found no documentation  here: https://github.com/minhhung2556/romantic_project_flutter_horizontal_featured_list

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Listview.builder` which has a `context` and `index`.

for tap you can use `inkWell` or [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Here is the [example](https://medium.com/@CodeSports/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb) for `listview.builder`

Comment: Thanks Hayi! Ended up doing it and everything is now working as I wanted.

Comment: always Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) or [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)() as a return Widget of the builder the add the function inside the you can get Widget index.